# What's the legal consequence of leaving the United States without using one's U.S. passport?

Tags: united-states, travel, passport, penalty

I read on [https://travel.state.gov](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/Advice-about-Possible-Loss-of-US-Nationality-Dual-Nationality/Dual-Nationality.html):

> U.S. nationals, including dual nationals, must use a U.S. passport to enter and leave the United States. Dual nationals may also be required by the foreign country to use its passport to enter and leave that country. Use of the foreign passport to travel to or from a country other than the United States is not inconsistent with U.S. law.

What's the legal consequence of leaving the United States without using one's U.S. passport?

Comment: How does one use their American passport to leave the United States?

Comment: @DJohnM One typically doesn't. But the question of whether one has left the United States without using one's U.S. passport may arise when entering the US without one's US passport.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt One usually implicitly does — by using the passport to book/check-in flights. The authorities will have access to this info.

Comment: @Greendrake  thanks, good point I hadn't thought of it. I don't know whether one uses the passport used to depart or the passport used to enter when booking and checking in.

Comment: This topic comes up frequently on [Travel.SE].

Comment: @phoog thanks, sorry I thought it would be too legal for travel.

Comment: @Greendrake: not really. I use my EU passport to check in for an EU bound flight. When I leave the US  (for Europe), my US passport is not used at all: neither for booking or check- in. I DO use my US passport for entry into the US.

Comment: @Hilmar Well, the majority of US passport holders don't have another one to use when checking in.

Comment: @Greendrake indeed.  That's why this question is of practical interest primarily for those who are dual citizens of the United States and another country.  In many cases it will be advantageous or possibly even required to check in for a flight leaving the US with a foreign passport, and the airline's system may not support sending one passport record to the US and a different passport record to the destination country for the same flight.  It's therefore useful to know that checking in with the foreign passport is not actually prohibited.

Answer (score 3):

The State Department is mischaracterizing the law, which requires only that the US citizen "bear" a valid US passport, not that the US citizen "use" the passport.

This law, [8 USC 1185(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1185#b), used to have a fairly stiff penalty, and it used to apply only in time of war.  When the wartime element was removed in 1978, so was the penalty.  It now reads

> Except as otherwise provided by the President and subject to such limitations and exceptions as the President may authorize and prescribe, it shall be unlawful for any citizen of the United States to depart from or enter, or attempt to depart from or enter, the United States unless he bears a valid United States passport.

If a US citizen attempts to leave the US without a valid US passport, there is a very small chance that the departure could be prevented by a CBP officer, but in the normal course of affairs the traveler would not even encounter a CBP officer, so the possibility is very remote indeed.

There is nothing, however, that prevents a US citizen who also holds a passport issued by another country from using the other passport while also carrying a valid US passport.

See also

- [What is the penalty for US citizens entering/leaving the US on a foreign passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/86059/19400) at [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com) and
- [Can someone be penalized for an "unlawful" act if no penalty is specified?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/38991/333) on this site.